# how to select record in given dates

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named rooms_booked and field is:

id, room_id, check_in_date, check_out_date.

how can i search those record which is booked between to  given dates

say i want to search those record which is booked between 16-04-2011 to 19-04-2011.

thanks in advance

Comment: Guessing it's a mysql-table you're talking about? You really should tag the quetstion better if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

Try using following query:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms_booked WHERE check_in_date BETWEEN '16-04-2011' AND '19-04-2011'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM rooms_booked 
WHERE check_in_date BETWEEN '16-04-2011' AND '19-04-2011'
```

Using [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)